# How can we run the PHP artisan commands in python

Tags: php, python, laravel

How can we run the given bellow PHP artisan commands in python script

`php artisan config:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Do you just want to call them using Python?

Comment: Yes. I want to call these using python. @James

Comment: This is all depending on how you use python or any python framework. How do you cache? How do you build views? Are you caching your routes?

Comment: it hava nothing to do with PHP or Python. `artisan` is just a PHP script from Laravel framework

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt maybe you should try hard to answer instead of closing it.

Comment: How can I answer a question that I can't understand? Please also keep in mind that SO intends to provide a knowledge base of problems and their solutions. An unclear question isn't useful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os
os.system('cd /var/www/xyz.com/ && php artisan config:cache')
os.system('cd /var/www/xyz.com/ && php artisan view:clear')
os.system('cd /var/www/xyz.com/ && php artisan route:cache')
```

Run the above code in python script and it will do the job. (Suppose www.xyz.com is your site)